# The argument type 'Future<ThemeMode> Function()' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'ThemeMode'

Tags: flutter, dart, future

i need to create a dark or light theme according to the user preferences, but the error "The argument type 'Future Function()' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'ThemeMode'."
occurs.

**the code is:**

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return NeumorphicApp(
      themeMode:getThemeTypeFromSharedPreferencess ,
           ),
}}
```

**the function is:**

```
Future<ThemeMode> getThemeTypeFromSharedPreferencess()async{
    if( await getThemeType.call() ==false){
      return ThemeMode.light;
    }else{
      return ThemeMode.dark;
    }    
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or you can do this async code in your void main as follows:-

```
void main()async{
  ThemeMode mode;
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  if( await getThemeType.call() ==false){
      mode=ThemeMode.light;
    }else{
      mode=ThemeMode.dark;
    }   
   runApp(MyApp(mode));//pass the mode to MyApp and then use it to show the theme
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final ThemeMode mode;
  MyApp(this.mode);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return NeumorphicApp(
      themeMode:mode,
           ),
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens because your `getThemeTypeFromSharedPreferencess` function returns a `Future` and the `themeMode` requires `ThemeMode` and not a `Future` of `ThemeMode`. To fix this you can use [FutureBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) and show a e.g. a [CircularProgressIndicator](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/CircularProgressIndicator-class.html) until the `Future` returns the `themeMode` and then you can set it in your `NeumorphicApp`.